# Exporting Table from a pdf file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabulate

I need to export the table from the pdf and select the particular columns.
I have managed to export by the "tabulate","tabula", however it is not exporting in the proper format. In the original file, there are 5 columns, but after exporting I get 3 columns totally because first three columns are considered as one for some reason.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8pi0.png)

Here is the table of the original table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8pi0.png)

Below is my code with the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW6WZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEIZ8.png)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Exactly the column that is taken as a one originally consist of 3 columns, so just thinking how to separate them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: imported packages (tabulate, pandas, tabulate.io)                         file= "name of file"                       dfs = read_pdf(file, pages="all",  pandas_options={'header':None})            
 dfs[0].columns = ["Structure ","Latitude","Longitude"]                                                                             
lat = dfs[0][3:]                                                                                                         
lat.iloc[0]["Longitude"]

Comment: Reason why i added 3 columns instead of 5, because it does not run I other way. I got value: '16° 03’ 53.80628”' from one columns. Now trying to export it as decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dfs = read_pdf(file, pages="all",  pandas_options={'header':None})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now i get tables without column names, which I can assign manually. The point I can not understand Is that why it creates table with 3 columns not 5 as it is in the original table

Comment: Maybe because of the merged cells. I would have to test it with your pdf to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support. I am so sorry that , I do not have a right for sharing file.